# check if UICollectionView is on top (not-scrolled) or not

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I would like to make an animation that would scroll to the top of UICollectionView, if it is not on the top already.

Is there any way to tell if UICollectionView is scrolled to the top or not?

Thank you.

Comment: Look at the docs for `UICollectionView`. What is its parent class?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the contentOffset property:

```
if (self.collectionview.contentOffset.y < 0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

If `collectionView.contentOffset == CGPointZero` you can say, that it is not scrolled at all.

Comment: I tried this one, but it throws an error of "Invalid operands to binary expression ..."